How to Convert Parent Page's URL in Singular Name format when Child page is open
I am trying to Convert the Parent Page URL into Sinular Name format when the child page is open, for instance:
Parent Page: abc.com/courses 
The child Page Should be: abc.com/course/course-name 

(Required this format when child page open removed s from parent name URL only).
I don't need this format to create another page with the course name redirecting to courses and call the child page's parent course.

When registering your CPT, the rewrite and has_archive parameters will control the URLs (untested):
register_post_type( 'course', array(
    ...
    'rewrite' => array(
        'with_front' => false,
        'slug'       => 'course',
    ),
    'has_archive' => 'courses',
);


The question is related to Page not from the custom post types.
For Instance, the Parent Page is courses, and the child page is photoshop.
The prefix will set
courses/photoshop  
I need a prefix like this.
course/photoshop.  
Only s should be removed from the parent URL name. While courses should be the parent page of Photoshop.

Oh! You'd need to experiment with rewrite rules. It will likely be flimsy, but could probably work.

Is it possible, without the CPT rewrite, that we can change the parent Purular prefix URL name with a Singular Prefix? Whereas parents should have the same Purular prefix of each child page. Only hide s from prefixes.
Currently, I am using the Following Method.
I created 2 Pages: the first one is Courses, and the second is Course (the course page is noindex and redirects to the courses page.) The Parent page of each child page is a course.

The courses Page shows all child pages, but when the child page opens, the prefix will show course/photoshop.
The Prefix URL structure is correct according to my needs. However, I am confused because it will not display the correct prefix child in Google Indexing.

Another example is Countries, which shows the all-countries list; when someone opens a single country, for instance, the USA, the prefix should be country/usa, not countries/usa etc. Please check the Page:
Countries List
